# Categorias e Subcategorias não atualizam - PHP7

Tags: php, ajax

Iniciando em programação estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação com `PHP` 7 e `MySql` baseado em um site de achados e perdidos, mas com problemas na criação do ***MENU***, onde minha base está na foto abaixo:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu consigo listar as categorias e as subcategorias referente a ela, mas ao clicar em outra categoria não traz as subcategorias pois necessita do `ID` da categoria.

Minha duvida seria a seguinte, primeiro gostaria de ao clicar em *categorias* exibir os itens da *subcategoria* na mesma pagina, ao selecionar outra *categoria*, automaticamente a *subcategoria* referente a categoria será listada e vi que posso fazer isso com `Ajax` e `jQuery`, testei vários métodos mas não obtive sucesso.

Alguém teria algum script parecido ou poderia me dar um norte? Talvez algum exemplo de como montar este menu.

Comment: Pode acontecer do seu sistema ter mais níveis de subcategorias? Ou sempre será Categoria->Subcategoria?

Comment: Diego Machado, este sistema irá possuir apenas Categoria e subcategoria.
Não irá existir 3 níveis

Comment: Preciso apenas entender melhor sua questão. Você gostaria de clicar em uma categoria e exibir as subcategorias referente a ela? E também exibir todos os produtos? Não ficou tão claro a sua dúvida, se puder reformular seria mais fácil.

Comment: Vamos lá, este menu ( categorias e subcategorias) serão utilizados em um formulario de cadastro. Eu gostaria de listar  conforme a foto acima, sendo que, este sistema irá possuir apenas Categoria e subcategoria.Gostaria que a partir da lista de categorias eu consiga abrir as subcategorias, e caso eu mude a categoria antrs de enviar o formulário, a mesma também atualize . Da seguinte forma: selecionei carros -> Fusca, caso eu mude a categoria para eletrônicos eu gostaria que a lista de subcategorias também fossem atualizadas de acordo com a categoria e na mesma página.

Comment: Ok, agora entendi o que precisa. Bom, não é tão simples a ponto de um pequeno script resolver. Não sei quais códigos já possui mas vou falar um pouco da lógica que pensei.. Basicamente você teria que ter dois hidden fields no form, e cada vez que clicar em uma categoria atualizar o valor do primeiro hidden com o id da categoria e o segundo com o id da subcategoria(caso haja). Para trocar de categoria como falou, seria o mesmo processo, criar um evento onclick para categoria e chamar o ajax para carregar a lista de categorias. Nesse mesmo evento onclick, o hidden field seria atualizado, etc..

Comment: Me fale caso tenha alguma dificuldade em algum desses pontos que citei

Comment: Ok, captei a ideia, estou longe do PC agora, vou ler mais a respeito do Ajax e tentar montar com essa lógica, agradeço pela ajuda